# Get a reference to a Backbone Marionette module without creating it

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone/Marionette application with asynchronous loading of modules.  That is, all modules are defined with `startWithParent = false` and I only load them as needed.  However, at certain points in the application, I need to get a reference to a module, but I have no idea if it was loaded yet.  Unfortunately, according to the docs, the command to get a reference to a module...

```
var module = App.module('Foobar');
```

...will also create a module with that name if one doesn't already exist.  This is problematic because the newly created module is empty.  Even worse, later in the application when I need to actually load the module for real, the module has already been created and the way Marionette is designed, you can't overwrite the module once it's been created.

So my question is, is there any method or workaround, to get a reference to a module without creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  Marionette puts a reference to the module under the App object.  So, a module **Foobar** would be accessed as **App.Foobar** or **App['Foobar']**.  If it's undefined then the module has not been created yet.